# "margin-left" in IE9

Tags: css, absolute

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

.rightBann{
    float:right;
    width:188px;
    height:254px;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-left:0 none;
    border-top:1px solid #ddd;
}

<div class="rightBann" style="position:absolute; background-color:#ffffff; margin-left:110px;">
    Object
</div>
```

It's saw perfect on Crome browser. But in IE9 there is another 110px of space on the left side of Object.(Total 220px from left)
What's going on this CSS?

Comment: Document Type : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: There's an extra 110px of space because you're setting `margin-left:110px`. What are you expecting?

Comment: your code is true.problem is your ie9 options. this code is working in mine.you can force the mode with a meta tag. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I used `padding-left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZQMew/